# Eclipse package explorer doesn't show X-icons upon compilation problematic java files

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, package-explorer

I've downloaded a brand new Eclipse from the official website. It's really nice.

The thing is, when I change some java file causing a compilation error in another java file, the package explorer donsn't show the little X icon upon the errored file.

When I open the errored file, the editor recognize that there is a bug there, mark the problematic line with red color. But still, in the package explorer - nothing.

When I change the file and save it again, only then, it shows the X icon on the package explorer.

I checked the "Build Automatically" on the project menu...

Does anyone know what's wrong, or ever solved this thing??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go to Problem tap next to the console tap, right click on it an select show in PackageExplorer

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

I had to open project properties --> builders, and there had to choose only "java builder", and delete another ANT builder I had there.

Then it worked immediately.

:)